# How to ignore a Maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

We have a groupId for Maven plugins:

```
com.company.maven.plugins
```

Unfortunately, when I created the first plugin in this groupId, I initially used the wrong naming convention.

```
maven-myplugin-plugin
```

The 1.x versions of the plugin used that name. When I realized this was wrong I changed the name to meet the [correct convention](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html).

```
myplugin-maven-plugin
```

Then I updated the version to 2.x.

In my local settings.xml file I use the `pluginGroups` to access my plugins from the command line. This particular plugin does not have to be specified in the pom file.

Unfortunately, when I try to access my plugin from the command line without scoping the name I always get the latest version of the incorrect naming convention. So, I get a 1.x version.

Can I tell Maven to ignore the `maven-myplugin-plugin` artifacts when accessing from the command line (i.e. `mvn myplugin:mygoal`)?

Some projects still use the old 1.x plugins, so I don't want to delete them from our repository. Also, we are using at least Maven 3.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It somehow seems that Maven3 resolves the prefixes from plugins in the order of

```
1. maven-myplugin-plugin
2. myplugin-maven-plugin
3. ... hard-wired groups ...
```

Following the official naming convention it *should* be the other way round imho. Nevertheless, I think you do not have a chance to get this fixed. I tried a set of things, basically playing around with the [goalPrefix](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) in the maven-plugin-plugin config. Installing a new version of the deprecated-named plugin with *goalPrefix* did not work. I guess one thing you could do is defining another prefix for your correctly-named plugin, e.g.:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
        <goalPrefix>myplugin2</goalPrefix>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Another approach could be to adjust the *old* plugin's pom.xml, renaming it to something different. But this would imply that your colleagues would need a different execute a different mvn command. Or you can rename your current plugin - similar results.

If there is a better solution, I would also be interested!

Comment: I ended up renaming the plugin. Thanks for the suggestions.